# ssh non-transparent jumphost

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell

This seems basic thing but I'm not able to find solution which completely satisfies.

Client ssh --->  Server A ssh ----> Server B

It is of course easy to do by typing commands while you login first A and then B. But I have specific requirements for Server A:

- Automatically ssh to server B (passwordless login already enabled)
- Automatically log-out also from Server A when session in Server B ends
- Do a logging (text file) of session. No need to cover in this answer as there is many instructions for that.
- Simply, the user should not be allowed to do anything in Server A, instead directly go to Server B. But transparent tunneling or jumphost is not an option because needs to log the session.

Comment: Just to clarifiy - does the user logon to A then the same credentials are used to logon to B, OR connect to A and get redirected to B with logging,

Comment: Different credentials. So there will be necessary keys in server A for login to Server B. The user does not provide even the host/ip address of Server B.

Comment: more generic: connect to A and get redirected to B with logging,

Comment: Use ``ProxyJump` or `ProxyCommand`.

Comment: I don't see ProxyJump` or ProxyCommand as an option. That is because they need actions on the client side and also not sure if session logging is possible in Server A in that case.

Comment: You could perhaps use forced commands defined in the `authorized_keys` file on A that then spawn a subsequent ssh to B (with logging as desired).

Answer (score 1):

### Just did this to create a jumphost without having to login twice.

In sshd_config add the following to serverA:

```
allowgroups users  
Match group users  
   ForceCommand ssh_forcecommand.sh
```

ssh_forcecommand.sh

```
if [ -z "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" ]; then  
  echo "usage ..."  
else  
  ssh $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND  
fi
```

In my case I use the parameter after the host (your serverA) as the destination host (your serverB). The linux ssh client will not request a terminal if you put anything after the host, ie: a command.   You will have to use the -t option on the client to enforce allocating a terminal.

ssh -t serverA serverB ---> serverA ---> serverB